# How to specify parameter "meta" in Dask Series.apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a function `features_extract`that take a string `r` as input and returns a list `[r, 3, 6]`. I want to apply this function on a series `s`. Then it returns an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`.

Could you please explain where I got wrong?

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
client = Client()

s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])

def features_extract(r):
    return [r, 6, 7]

meta = [(0, 'f8'), (1, np.int64), (2, np.int64)]

s = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions = 5)
s = s.apply(features_extract, meta = meta)
s.compute(scheduler = 'processes')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `meta` option you are passing the properties of the object that is returned by the function, but the item returned by function `features_extract` is a list, not a pandas series. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Changing `meta` option to `list` (dask will not care about the dtypes inside the list):

```py
s = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions = 5)
s = s.apply(features_extract, meta = list)
s.compute(scheduler = 'processes')
```

2. Change the function output to a pandas series, then dask would use the dtypes you specify:

```py
def features_extract(r):
    return pd.Series([r, 6, 7])

meta = [(0, 'f8'), (1, np.int64), (2, np.int64)]

s = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions = 5)
s = s.apply(features_extract, meta = meta)
s.compute(scheduler = 'processes')
```

See [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html) for further information.

Comment: Your answer which is a great help for me. Could you elaborate how to specify the meta in case our function returns a dictionary `{'name': r, 'num1': 6, 'num2': 6}`. I guess it may be either `[('name', 'f8'), ('num1', np.int64), ('num2', np.int64)]` or `{'name': 'f8', 'num1': np.int64, 'num2': np.int64}`, but I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: If the returned value is a dictionary, you would specify `meta = dict`. (dask would not check the `dtype` inside the dictionary)