# Is it possible to automatically chunk a csv when processing with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a csv file where I validate the each cell by some rule on the column.

```py
df.drop(df[~validator].index, inplace=True)
```

The validator here is can be different functions checking if a cell is integer-like, or if a string inside a cell is smaller than 10 characters etc. So a cell alone hase all the information to be validated without requiring any other cells from the same row or same column.

And I have this:

```py
    bad_dfs = []
    for validator, error in people_csv_validators:
        bad_dfs.append(df.loc[~validator])
        df.drop(df[~validator].index, inplace=True)
    bad_df = pd.concat(bad_dfs)
```

Prior the dataframes were smaller than 1m rows with 20 columns or less, column count didn't change but the rows increased by a lot and I want to be able to process this with a fixed amount of memory.  So I figured I'd chunk it since the validation doesn't depend on anything.

Now, I know I can just put chunk argument in to the read_csv I have, then write to a csv file chunk by chunk with mode="a", but I head about `dask` and couple other libraries that does something similar underneath with their dataframe class, and I figured there might be some other methods to do this.

Is there any standard way of doing this, like

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, chunk_in_the_background_and_write_to_this_file=output_path, chunk_count=10^6)

some_row_based_operations(df)

# It automatically reads the first 10^6 rows and processes them,
# then writes them to `output_path` and then reads the next 10^6 rows and so on
```

Again, this is rather a simple thing but I want to know if there is a canonical way.

Comment: I don't think Pandas has that functionality, every dataframe is in-memory. The closest that it has, like you said, is the chunk argument and loop.

Comment: I see, I'll checkout dask, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough code to do this with dask is as follows:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

# let's use ddf for dask df
ddf = dd.read_csv(path) # can also provide list of files

def some_row_based_operations(df):
    # a function that accepts and returns pandas df
    # implementing required logic
    return df

# the line below is fine only if the function is row-based
# (no dependencies across different rows)
modified_ddf = ddf.map_partitions(some_row_based_operations)

# single_file kwarg is only if you want one file at the end
modified_ddf.to_csv(output_path, single_file=True)
```

One caution: with the approach above there should be no inplace changes to the df inside `some_row_based_operations`, but hopefully making a change like the one below is feasible:

```py
# change this: df.drop(df[~validator].index, inplace=True)
# also note, that this logic should be part of `some_row_based_operations`
df = df.drop(df[~validator].index)
```

Comment: I'm playing around with this but I couldn't figure something out. If I have a machine with a single core and thread to run this, so no parallel stuff: does dask automatically chunk the df and process a single chunk, then write it to output_path, then continue this through the chunks? I basically want to know if I specify  blocksize=25e6 in read_csv, and if this 25mb takes X amount of ram when converted into an actual pandas dataframe, is dask going to be using X amount of ram in total, or X*block_count (which defeats the whole purpose). I played around but couldn't test it properly.

Comment: using memory_profiler library it seems like it actually uses the same amount of ram with & without the dask in this case.

Comment: Hmm, yes, it's possible to explicitly specify the resources granted to dask, but for that one would need to instantiate cluster explicitly and define desired memory constraints for the workers, check: https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/worker-memory.html

Comment: Apparently dask doesn't support dropping rows like that but other than that, thanks. Now trying to rewrite my script so it doesn't use drops but instead .locs and stuff

Comment: Dask does support dropping of the rows IF this operation is inside a function passed to `.map_partitions`. In the snippet above, you can put row-drop logic inside `some_row_based_operations`.

Comment: Hmm I see. Yeah that seems to be the case, thank you. I've got one more problem which is that when I use dask it guesses the dtypes wrong unlike pandas. Anything I can do about that other than manually giving it the dtypes? This is just an extra question, though. I've accepted the answer as this is the correct answer. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, for specifying meta [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66728862/10693596) might be useful, and of course [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-design.html).